# Проблема лицензирования приложения с помощью Google Play Licensing на эмуляторах с API 28 и выше

Tags: android, google-play, лицензирование

Проверка лицензии моего андроид-приложения осуществляется с помощью библиотеки лицензирования Google Play Licensing Library. На AVD с API ниже 28 проблем нет, но на эмуляторах с API 28 и выше ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.verify(LicenseValidator.java:99).
```

Как тестировать проверку лицензии на эмуляторах с последними версиями API?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно войти в Google-аккаунт на эмуляторе.